# Looking for an app to notify when an elderly person is inactive

Tags: applications

I am looking for an android app to install on the phone of an elderly person in my family so that when this person stops using the phone, say for one day, then I get notified somehow so that I check up on them and make sure they are ok. Does something like this already exist?

Thanks.

Comment: Someone migrate this to [softwarerecs.se]?

Answer (score 0):

[SeniorSafety on GooglePlay](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.seniorsafety)

This application has an inactivity option as well as fall notifications, gps tracking and other useful options for senior safety.

Comment: It is not free, though (inactivity alerts are only available upon subscription). Are there any free alternatives?